# Turn tensor into a numpy array in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How do I turn a tensor such as `Tensor("lstm_42/Identity:0", shape=(1, 100, 13), dtype=float32)` into a numpy array in keras? Tried .numpy() and .eval() but nothing seems to work.

Using 2.3.0-tf

Comment: Calling .numpy() works fine for me in tf-2.3. be sure that your actually using v-2.3 and not an older version. Also `.eval()` isn't supported when running eagerly.

Comment: Apparently the model refuses to run in eager mode according to this. github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26268 

I tried adding run_eagerly=True to the compile function and dynamic=True to the model constructor, but got this error: `TypeError: ('Functional models may only specify 'name' and 'trainable' keyword arguments during initialization. Got an unexpected argument:', 'dynamic')`